# How to read CSV file in R with row title?

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I try to read this CSV file:

[image]

There are 3 columns in this file.
when I read it in R by read.csv("file.csv")
I get:

[image]

It read just 2 columns instead of 3 columns and did some mixed between them

any suggestions how to solve it will be welcome

Comment: Without a header row, use `read.table` instead. `read.csv` is *the same function*  but with some defaults set. It is deliberately inflexible, read `help("read.table")` carefully, it is explained there. If the error doesn't go away, please update the question with information on this.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could provide the top 10 or so lines from the raw text file (into a [code block]).

Comment: or just try `data.table::fread('file.csv')`

Comment: Can you share the csv file you are attempting to read into R?

Answer (score 2):

Likely you have an extra comma somewhere not expected.  For instance the data itself might contain a comma, or there is a hidden column in the data.

If you are editing in Excel, then highlight several empty columns at the end of your data and then hit the delete key.  Do the same for several rows beneath the last entry, then save the file again as a csv.

Also inspect your data for spurious commas.  This can happen if your data comes from a database, and someone randomly inserted a comma in your data.

Also sometimes source data stored with unicode characters that will get converted to other characters when imported into a program that is expecting UTF-8.

You can also inspect the file in notepad++, and turn on reveal codes.  This will highlight all spaces and special characters.  Sometimes there will be unexpected characters causing a misalignment of the data.